# How to dump a database from external url to Docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, dump

I want to dump tables from an amazon url into my mariadb container, but it doesn't work.
Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM amazoncorretto:11.0.15-alpine
LABEL website = "PHEDON"
VOLUME /phedon-app
RUN apk update && apk add --update --no-cache curl
RUN curl https://myurl/dbdump/dump.sql --output dump.sql
COPY . .
RUN chmod +x ./gradlew
RUN ./gradlew assemble
RUN mv ./build/libs/phedon-spring-server.jar app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","-Dspring.profiles.active=dev", "app.jar"]
EXPOSE 8080
```

And here is the db part of the docker compose file.

```
phedon_db:
    image: "mariadb:10.6"
    container_name: mariadb
    restart: always
    command:
      [ --lower_case_table_names=1 ]
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "mariadb-admin", "--protocol", "tcp" ,"ping" ]
      timeout: 3m
      interval: 10s
      retries: 10
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    networks:
      - phedon
    volumes:
      - container-volume:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./dump.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/dump.sql
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "phedondb"
      MYSQL_USER: "phedon"
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "12345"
      MARIADB_ALLOW_EMPTY_ROOT_PASSWORD: "true"
    env_file:
      - .env
networks:
  phedon:
volumes:
  container-volume:
```

I have tried to use the ADD command too, and still no results, my mariadb database is still empty.

Comment: You seem to be running the `curl` command inside a different image's Dockerfile, but you can't mount that file into the database container.  Download the file directly on the host system instead, outside the Dockerfile.  You could also consider using the `mysql` command-line tool to restore the dump, either from outside Docker (`mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3307 < dump.sql`) or from a sibling container (`mysql -h phedon_db < dump.sql`).

Comment: Yeah I guessed that could be the issue, but the main problem is I specifically don't want to download it into the host system.

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1:**

You can download the sql file which you want to restore directly on to the host system and can execute the below command to restore it

```
docker exec -i some-mysql sh -c 'exec mysql -u<user> -p<password> <database>' < /<path to the file>/dump.sql.sql
```

**Method 2**

As you are exposing the database on port 3307 you might try to connect to the database through a client. In case if you have installed mysql in your command line then you can execute the below command to restore it.

```
$  mysql --host=127.0.0.1 --port=3306 -u phedon -p phedon_db < dump.sql
```